# finding text between two specified words in Python, when one of the two words changes

Tags: python

Basically, I am trying to extract text between two strings within a loop as one of the two words changes after the information is extracted.

so for example, the string is:

```
string = alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end, 333 bravo somethingB end 444 alpha 555 bravo
```

So I want to extract the text between alpha and end and then bravo and end. I have quite a few of these unique words in my file so I have a list and a counter to go through them. See the code below:

```
string = 'alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end, 333 bravo somethingB end 444 alpha 555 bravo'
words = ['alpha', 'bravo'] #there will be more words here
counter = 0
stringOut = ''
#going through the list of words
while counter < len(words):

    firstWord = words[counter]
    lastWord = 'end'
    data = string[string.find(firstWord)+len(firstWord):string.find(lastWord)].strip()
    #this will give the text between the first ocurrance of "alpha" and "end"
    #since I want just the smallest string between "alpha" and "end", I use another    
    #while loop
    #to see if firstWord occurs again

    while firstWord in data:

        ignore,ignore2,data = data.partition(str(firstWord))
        counter = counter + 1 

    stringOut += str(data) + str('\n')
print('output string is \n' + str(stringOut))
#this code gives the correct output for the text between the first word ("alpha") and 
#"end".
#but when the list moves to the next string "bravo", it takes the text between the 
#first "bravo"
#and the "end" that was associated with the information required for "alpha" 
#("somethingA")
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: What is the output you need for: `alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end`?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that any text you already parsed is not useful anymore? so if you first extract `'alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end'` then you want to search only through the rest of the string, `', 333 bravo somethingB end 444 alpha 555 bravo'` ? kind of like slicing the string each time?

Comment: I need somethingA, then for the next word I need something B

Comment: and there are many of these words so, in a big text - i have lets say many alpha, bravo, charlie etc... and end. I want to extract all the text between "alpha" and "end", "bravo" and "end", "charlie" and "end" etc. hence using while loop. But alpha, bravo, charlie can appear more than once and i want only the smallest string that is within those two words

Answer (score 3):

I morphed your request into a method/function (iterator). I Hope this helps you :)

```
string = 'alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end, 333 bravo somethingB end 444 alpha 555 bravo'
words = ['alpha', 'bravo']

def method(string, words, end_word):
    segments = string.split(end_word)
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(words):
        data = segments[counter].split(words[counter])[-1]
        counter += 1
        yield data.strip()

for r in method(string, words, 'end'):
    print r

>>> 
somethingA
somethingB
```

note: this solution works if the string is being parsed forward and never needs to be looked back on.

Please note, that without further input from you, I do not know exactly how to restrict this, but at the moment, the length of words must be equal to or less then the number of `'end_word'` in the string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works exactly as expected. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Am I correct to assume that any text you already parsed is not useful anymore? so if you first extract 'alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end' then you want to search only through the rest of the string, ', 333 bravo somethingB end 444 alpha 555 bravo' ? kind of like slicing the string each time?

Yes you are correct in assuming that. Does the code you suggested slice the string?

Comment: and what could you do if you want the string to remain the same and search from it again later one?
so when you find the somethingA, when searching for somethingB - the whole string is intact?

Comment: So for example, in my words list I have 'alpha' again ['alpha', 'bravo', alpha']. Using the splitting function omitts the part and hence if the information is required again then it can no longer be found.

Comment: you pass the string into the function, but the original string is still intact, but within the function it is sliced up and consumed for the desired result. run your own tests on it if you want. :)

Comment: I think the issue is the for loop.
in my actual string the string is slightly different. 

string = alpha charlie somethingA end, bravo delta somethingB end 

so somethingA is the information for both alpha and charlie. and somethingB is for both Bravo and Delta. So, the output should be :

for alpha: "charlie somethingA", Bravo: "Delta somethingB", then for Charlie: "somethingA", Delta: "somethingB". This doesn't happen as the for loop only processes the whole string once. Any idea how to avoid this? Thanks so much

Comment: so when i asked you "text you already parsed is not useful anymore?" and you said "yes" you were mistaken, in this case, the parsed text is still important. and you can not just slice it away. this solution will not work for you, i can propose a different solution, but you can also take the regex solution by [ATOzTOA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14685198/1561176)

Comment: my bad - Sorry about the confusion. is it possible to use similar solution you proposed but without using for loop to avoid this issue?
regex solutions works in small test cases. However, as my text is quite a big text file - this is really slow and I can't really use this.

Comment: sure, i can stitch something together. give me a while, i will post as a second answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
import re

string = 'alpha 111 bravo 222 alpha somethingA end, 333 bravo somethingB end 444 alpha 555 bravo'
words = ['alpha', 'bravo'] #there will be more words here

for word in words:
    expr = re.compile(r'.*' + word + '(.+?)end');
    out = expr.findall(string)
    print word + " => " + str(out[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> 
alpha =>  somethingA 
bravo =>  somethingB
```

Comment: Thank you AToz. This works great as well! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Using your new subset:

```
string = 'alpha bravo ... alpha charlie somethingAC end ... ... bravo delta somethingBD end alpha ... bravo ...'
words = ['alpha','bravo','charlie','delta']

def method(string, words, end_word, single=True):
    segments = string.split(end_word)
    for word in words:
        for segment in segments:
            if word in segment:
                data = segment.split(word)[-1]
                yield (word, data.strip())
                if single:
                    break
```

Notice the new argument: `single` by default, only one result per word will be yeilded, but if you want, it will search for each word in each segment of the string, since I am not sure what you want, you can always remove it later.

```
# each word only once
for r in method(string, words, 'end'):
    print r

>>> 
('alpha', 'charlie somethingAC')
('bravo', '... alpha charlie somethingAC')
('charlie', 'somethingAC')
('delta', 'somethingBD')
```

and:

```
# each word for each segment
for r in method(string, words, 'end', False):
    print r   

>>>
('alpha', 'charlie somethingAC')
('alpha', '... bravo ...')
('bravo', '... alpha charlie somethingAC')
('bravo', 'delta somethingBD')
('bravo', '...')
('charlie', 'somethingAC')
('delta', 'somethingBD')
```

As a bonus, I am including this generator expression in list-comprehension form:

```
def method1(string, words, end_word, single=True):
    return ([(word, segment.split(word)[-1]) for segment in string.split(end_word) if word in segment][:(1 if single else None)] for word in words)
```

Comment: Hi Inbar, single=True does not give all the data required. Data for Alpha, charlie and delta are correct, but not for Bravo. It should give ('Bravo', 'Delta somethingBD'). I think the reason is, it looks for any occurence of word in the segment and hence when the first bravo occurs in the first segment it outputs ('...alpha charlie somethingAC') and hence doesn't go to the next segment where the real data for 'bravo' is. FOr 'delta' this works as 'delta' is not present in the first segment and only present in the second segment.

Comment: Look, first of all, you have the option to turn off `single`. Secondly neither the code nor I can read your mind. You input a single string, and a list of words, the rules are that you either find the first occurrence of the word in the string or every occurrence of the word in the string, it can not magically detect which particular segment you wanted to find the word in. I am not sure what kind of solution you want that can automatically read your mind and know which segment of the string to look in.

Comment: hmm, i understand you can turn off single. I think I wasn't clear enough so I wrote it as an answer below. I think i can work with the information even if not exactly as desired. Thank you for your help